# SCIF Issue on Xeon Phi

Tags: c, xeon-phi

I am trying to use SCIF inter-process communication on Xeon Phi. My program has two processes, one process writes data to another process using scif_writeto. Currently, I encountered an error " No device or address" for the scif_writeto API. I checked that the end point is set up correct, the offset is also returned correctly. I don't have any idea about what's going wrong here. Is there any good suggestion to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In user mode scif_writeto() returns -1 in case of fail and set errno to indicate the error. Possible errors are described in scif.h.
You could check the errno to debug your problem.